# Calculating Time Complexity of recursice function

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, recurrence

So i have the following code and I cant figure out how to get the recurrence relation for it. I finally need to calculate the time complexity of the code.

```
int countChangeRec(int amount, array<int, 5>coins, int n)
{
    if(amount == 0)
        return 0;
    if((amount > 0 && n < 0) || (amount < 0))
        return INT_MAX;


    if(amount < coins[n-1])
        return countChangeRec(amount, coins, n-1);

    return min(countChangeRec(amount, coins, n-1), 
        amount / coins[n-1]+ countChangeRec(amount%coins[n-1], coins, n));
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice on how to go about doing this.

Comment: Also any optimizations would be appreciated. Need to solve using recursion. I know the DP solution but any optimizations in the above method would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be obvious, but please add how you call the function the first time to start things off.

Comment: Also, I might be wrong but I think your code has a bug when `n` is (or becomes) zero and `amount` is non-zero, because you access `coins[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not solve the problem. If you want to calculate the minimum number of coins, here's an example that breaks your solution

```
coins = {1,9,10}
amount = 37
```

Your solution return the answer 5, but the right answer is 4

```
9*3 + 1*10
```